# Indent tasks on import from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I would like to indent tasks on import from Excel. I have working solution for importing tasks, however I can't find a solution for indenting tasks in MS Project without adding something to text name, like:

```
    If (Not IsEmpty(Range("AJ" & i).Value)) And (Not IsError(Range("AJ" & i).Value)) Then

        Select Case Left(newproj.Tasks(i - 7).Name, 3)
        Case "( ", "Op-"
          newproj.Tasks(i - 7).OutlineIndent
        End Select

    End If
```

This is OK, but does not look nice when there is something like "Op-" in front of task name. Is it possible to Indent while importing?

Here is my code for importing tasks:

```
For i = 8 To 90

    strValue = Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("AK" & i)

    If (Not IsEmpty(Range("AK" & i).Value)) And (Not IsError(Range("AK" & i).Value)) Then

        newproj.Tasks.Add strValue

    End If

Next i
```

My tasks in Excel are in column AK, in helper column AJ there are Op- values to identify what should be indented and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution with using `OutlineLevel`. If somebody is interested in code, it is here:

```
   If (Range("AK" & i).Value <> "") And (Not IsError(Range("AK" & i).Value)) Then

            newproj.Tasks.Add strValue

                Select Case Range("AJ" & i).Value
                Case "Op-"
                    newproj.Tasks(i - 7).OutlineLevel = 2
                Case "As-"
                    newproj.Tasks(i - 7).OutlineLevel = 1
                End Select

        End If
```